Is there a Conditional Random Field (CRF) Layer in latest Keras or Tensorflow or Keras-NLP?
I was exploring CRF for NER task. I recently got to know that CRF layer is present in Tensorflow Addons but it has been archived till May2024. I would like to know any of these Keras, Tensorflow, Keras-NLP have latest implementations of the layer?
